# In mysql, how will I show all category in table even without data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I AM USING MYSQL 8.0.
THIS IS MY DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE AA (
A int
);

insert into AA (A) values (1);
insert into AA (A) values (1);
insert into AA (A) values (2);
insert into AA (A) values (2);
insert into AA (A) values (1);
insert into AA (A) values (9);
insert into AA (A) values (NULL);

CREATE TABLE BB (
code int,
description varchar(30)
);

insert into BB (code, description) values (1, 'Male');
insert into BB (code, description) values (2, 'Female');
insert into BB (code, description) values (3, 'No Response');
```

THIS IS THE QUERY:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT MAX(CASE 
           WHEN a.A IS NULL THEN 9
           WHEN b.code IS NULL THEN 8
           ELSE a.A
         END  
     ) CODE,
     CASE 
       WHEN a.A IS NULL THEN 'BLANK' 
       WHEN b.code IS NULL THEN 'NOT VALID'
       ELSE b.description 
     END SEX,
     COUNT(*) TOTAL,
     ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (), 2) PERCENT
FROM AA a LEFT JOIN BB b ON b.code = a.A
GROUP BY SEX
)
SELECT CODE, SEX, TOTAL, PERCENT, 
   SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) CUMULATIVE, 
   ROUND(100.0 * SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) / SUM(TOTAL) OVER (), 2) CUMPERCENT
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 'TOTAL', COUNT(*), 100.00, 0, 0.00
FROM AA
ORDER BY CODE;
```

THIS IS THE OUTPUT:

```
CODE | SEX     | TOTAL | PERCENT | CUMULATIVE | CUMPERCENT
0      TOTAL     7       100.00    0            0.00
1      MALE      3       42.86     3            42.86
2      FEMALE    2       28.57     5            71.43
8      NOT VALID 1       14.29     6            85.71
9      BLANK     1       14.29     7            100.00
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
CODE | SEX        | TOTAL | PERCENT | CUMULATIVE | CUMPERCENT
0      TOTAL        7       100.00    0            0.00
1      Male         3       42.86     3            42.86
2      Female       2       28.57     5            71.43
3      No Response  0       0.00      5            71.43
8      NOT VALID    1       14.29     6            85.71
9      BLANK        1       14.29     7            100.00
```

This was just an update from my previous question. I just want to show in the output table all the category even if there are no data on it. In my expected output, the 'No Response' is '0' (or blank/NULL) since there is no value on it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You need FULL JOIN of source tables, not `FROM AA a LEFT JOIN BB b`. It is not implemented in MySQL. So perform it in additional CTE using UNION.

Comment: @Akina But how will I insert the TOTAL, NOT VALID, BLANK in the source table since it was only a derived value? sorry.. I was just new to this MySQL programming.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
-- adjust table AA
cte1 AS (SELECT COALESCE(A, 8) A
         FROM AA),
-- adjust table BB
cte2 AS (SELECT code, description
         FROM BB
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 8, 'NOT VALID'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 9, 'BLANK'),
-- join and calculate counts
cte3 AS (SELECT cte2.code CODE, 
                cte2.description SEX, 
                COUNT(cte1.A) TOTAL
         FROM cte2
         LEFT JOIN cte1 ON cte1.A = cte2.code
         GROUP BY cte2.code, cte2.description)
-- calculate cumulative values
SELECT CODE,
       SEX,
       TOTAL,
       ROUND(100.0 * TOTAL / SUM(TOTAL) OVER (), 2) PERCENT,
       SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) CUMULATIVE ,
       ROUND(100.0 * SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) / SUM(TOTAL) OVER (), 2) CUMUPERCENT
FROM cte3
UNION ALL
-- and add totals
SELECT 0,
       'TOTAL',
       (SELECT SUM(TOTAL) FROM cte3),
       100, 
       0,
       0
ORDER BY CODE
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b24615d0fecbdd1272de35e058f3471)

Comment: @CarloKarganilla I'd recommend you to adjust the tables data. Add rows into table BB. Add generated column into table AA. This may increase the performance dramatically - now this query cannot use tables indices.

Comment: Thank you. This was just one example that I am tabulating. There were reference tables that have lots of codes with description, it will be hard to determine what will be the invalid codes. Can I add another question regarding this query?

Comment: @CarloKarganilla Another question - another topic. Rever to this topic if you think that this is useful.

Comment: Ok.. Thank you for your help. I will just add another question related to this..

Answer (score 0):

If you add these 3 records to table BB:

```
insert into BB (code, description) values (8, 'NOT VALID'); 
insert into BB (code, description) values (9, 'BLANK');
```

and update AA like this:

```
UPDATE AA SET A=8 WHERE A IS NULL;
```

You could also do this:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
     COALESCE(b.code,0) as CODE, 
     b.description as SEX, 
     COUNT(a.A) TOTAL,
     ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(a.A) / SUM(COUNT(a.A)) OVER (), 2) PERCENT
FROM AA a RIGHT JOIN BB b ON b.code = a.A
GROUP BY SEX
)
SELECT CODE, SEX, TOTAL, PERCENT, 
   SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) CUMULATIVE, 
   ROUND(100.0 * SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY CODE) / SUM(TOTAL) OVER (), 2) CUMPERCENT
FROM cte
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 0, 'TOTAL', COUNT(*), 100.00, 0, 0.00
 FROM AA
ORDER BY CODE;
```

The biggest change is changing the `LEFT JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN`.